# Referencing of sets in Pyomo objectives

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a question about referecing set in Pyomo objectives. Basically I have 2 options and I do not understand why one of it works whereas the other yields an error. Here you see them:

```
model.set_timeslots = pyo.RangeSet(0,95)

#Option1
def ObjectiveRule (model):
    return sum(model.variable_heatGeneration[t]  for t in model.set_timeslots)

model.objective_costs = pyo.Objective( rule=ObjectiveRule, sense =pyo.minimize)

#Option 2
def ObjectiveRule_2 (model, t):
    return sum(model.variable_heatGeneration[t])

model.objective_costs = pyo.Objective(model.set_timeslots, rule=ObjectiveRule_2, sense =pyo.minimize)
```

The second options leads to the error

> TypeError: '_GeneralVarData' object is not iterable

Can you tell me what the difference is and why the second option does not work?

Reminder: Can nobody tell me what the difference is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option makes sense to me : you are returning **a sum** such as :
$$
\sum_{t \in T} h_t
$$

where $h_t$ represents your `variable_heatGeneration` and $T$ your `set_timeslots`.

The second option I do not understand and am not surprised an error is raised. You are returning the sum of **a constant** $h_t$. I believe the error

> TypeError: '_GeneralVarData' object is not iterable

is raised because the object `model.variable_heatGeneration[t]` is constant and not an iterable object such as list. It is trying to sum over a constant which makes no sense.

In a sum, you need an iterable object, for example :

```
sum(x for x in range(10)) # sum over an iterable
sum(x for x in L) # if L is a list 
sum([x for x in range(10)]) # sum over a list
```

In option 2 you are doing something like

```
sum(x) # where x is a constant
# or 
sum(3)
```

To get rid of this specific error, try removing the sum :

```
#Option 2
def ObjectiveRule_2 (model, t):
    return model.variable_heatGeneration[t]
```

Note that this will probably create another error somewhere else, and it will not model the wanted cost function. Sticking with option $1$ is a better idea.

Comment: Thanks Kuifje for your answer. You wrote "model.variable_heatGeneration[t] is constant" --> This is not true. The variable_heatGeneration is a decision variable that should be determined by the solver. It depends on the set t and has one value for every t. This is why we can in fact sum it up variable_heatGeneration [1] + variable_heatGeneration [2] + ... variable_heatGeneration  [n]

Comment: You wrote "To get rid of this specific error, try removing the sum "--> This does not make sense at all because I do want to calculate the sum in the objective function.

Comment: I didn't say it would make any sense :) I said it would get rid of the specific error that is mentioned, and that indeed it does not model the wanted cost function.

Comment: "model.variable_heatGeneration[t]" is a variable. But for a given $t$ (input of ObjectiveRule_2), it will be a constant (the value of the variable). In all cases it is not an iterable object so you cannot sum over it, when $t$ is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort Kuifje. I really appreciate it. I do not understand why t is fixed in the scond option. I pass all the sets (model.set_timeslots) to the ObjectiveRule_2 (model, t) function. The variable model.variable_heatGeneration[t] depends on t and I just want to build the sum over all ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kuifje. Any comments to my last comment? I'd highly appreciate any further comments from you.

Comment: In the second option, $t$ is fixed because it is the input of the objective rule method (def ObjectiveRule_2 (model, t)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help Kuifje. I accepted and upvoted your answer. Further, I awarded the bounty to you. I really appreciate your help.